# How to change directory character in NetRW of Vim?

Tags: vim, netrw

The default file explorer inside Vim is NetRW. It can be invoked, for example, by using `:e .`. In its tree view, it prefixes the directory name with pipe characters (`|`).

For example:

```
joe/
| Desktop/
| Documents/
| Downloads/
```

How can I replace the pipe character with something else in the tree display of NetRW?

I have looked at the monster `netrw.vim` file and cannot seem to find this pipe character in it.

Comment: **Why** would you want to do this?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: To beautify the display a bit. I could replace the pipe with some of the fancy Unicode symbols :-)

Comment: Instead of modifying the plugin, I'd ask DrChip, its author, for support for such. Alternatively, you can switch to the NERD_Tree plugin; it allows to influence this via a config variable.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't look hard enough:

```
if has("gui_running") && (&enc == 'utf-8' || &enc == 'utf-16' || &enc == 'ucs-4')
 let s:treedepthstring= "│ "
else
 let s:treedepthstring= "| "
endif
```

Line 439 of `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim` (in version 151, at least).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of how to change it. I'm not a vim scripts expert, but it looks like the answer is that you can't?

Comment: If the question is "can it be done?", then the answer is "yes". If the question is "how can I do it?", then the answer is "get an up-to-date version of Netrw and make whatever change you want in the snippet above". If the question is "is there an option for that", the the answer is "no".